# I get a "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." error on my AIR project for using a button.

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe

So my problem here is, I'm working on my Adobe Air project, so I decided to code some buttons to be able to navigate. The problem here is that I get a error for trying to do so. Here is my code.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

this.stop();
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playButtonClick);

function playButtonClick(evt:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndPlay(337);
}
```

I do not see what is wrong actually, I tried this on a blank non-AIR file, and it worked well. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to say without the proper context, but that 1009 error means you are trying to access an object that is null.

From that very small snippet you've posted, either play_btn is null or as wwwOzOk says, frame 337 does not exit (although I'm not sure trying to move to a frame that doesn't exist would through 1009).

HTH

J

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.stop(); 

trace("Instance of play_btn: " +play_btn);

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playButtonClick);
function playButtonClick(evt:MouseEvent) 
{ 
    gotoAndPlay(337); 
}
```

If you get a << null >> value in trace then this means that your button was not instantiated at this frame. Make sure the button gets created before trying to access it ;)

Comment: I fixed it by making it a "Menu Item," all though, thanks for you're help! Really appreciate it.